# Reaching value within nested object within API

Tags: reactjs, api

I am trying to reach some nested values within an object in my API. I am also trying to pass these values as props from the child component to the parent component.

Everything works but I can't display any value within "address" and "company".

I am trying with {address.name} and {adress[0].name} but I get errors with both.

I would like to print street, suite, city, and zip code.

This is my API:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  },
```

This is what I am returning within the parent component:

```
return (
    <>
      <header>      
        <h1>Users list</h1>
      </header>
      <section> 
        <ul>
          {users.map(user => (
            <li key={user.id}>
              <button onClick ={() => setSelectedUser(user)}>{user.name}</button></li>
          ))}         
        </ul>

        {selectedUser && (
          <UserDetail 
            name={selectedUser.name} 
            username={selectedUser.username}
            email={selectedUser.email}
            adress={selectedUser.adress.street}
            phone={selectedUser.phone}
            company={selectedUser.company.name}
          />)}
      </section>
    </>
```

This is what I am passing from the child comp:

```
const UserDetail = ({name, username, email, adress, phone, website, company}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{name}</h1>
      <p>{username}</p>
      <p>{email}</p>
      <p>Adress:{adress.street}</p>
      <p>{phone}</p>      
      <p>{website}</p>      
      <p>{company.name}</p>      
    </div>
  )
}

export default UserDetail
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the response contains `address` but you are using with a single `s` `selectedUser.adress`.
For `company` you are passing the company name as props so you don't have to do again `company.name` but just `company`.

Comment: Thank you Antonio, the props are ALWAYS passed from parent to child right?

Comment: yes. and it is updated every time you click on the button because you are changing one state of the component. 
I guess you are using `const [selectedUser, setSelectedUser] = useState();` to keep track of the selected user, right ?